# Alter/change default value for sequence on postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, heidisql

I would like to alter my sequence value in database. On top of that, I tried to get the sequence info by below query

```
SELECT PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE('test_thing', 'id');
```

which is it return to NULL.

[image]

Further check in Postgres (using HeidiSQL) db for table test_thing, I can see my primary key default value is:

```
(nextval('test_thing_thing_seq_id'::regclass)
```

which I believe is causing the result to return to NULL and would like to change/alter the value as below

```
(nextval('test_thing_thing_id_seq'::regclass)
```

The questions are:

1. How I'm supposed to change the value without dropping the table and maintain the data
2. Or can I just change directly from here

[image]

3. Is there any future problem issue if I change directly as above (no.2)
   Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `pg_get_serial_sequence` will return the sequence name only if you have added a dependency between the sequence and the column; it does not look at the`DEFAULT` clause  You can add a dependency with

```
ALTER SEQUENCE test_thing_thing_id_seq
   OWNED BY test_thing(id);
```

You can change the sequence value with

```
SELECT setval('test_thing_thing_id_seq', 42);
```

That can probably also be done with a GUI client like HeidiSQL, but I don't know because I don't use GUI clients

Changing the sequence value can cause problems if the new value is lower than the maximum of `id` in the table: future `INSERT`s could result in primary key constraint violation errors

Comment: Yes you are right, I'm currently changing the sequence value as my app return those error ' primary key constraint violation errors '. Which is why I would like to change the (nextval('test_thing_thing_seq_id'::regclass) to (nextval('test_thing_thing_id_seq'::regclass). I'm not sure if the sequence of ...seq_id is the culprit on why when I run the query SELECT PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE('test_thing', 'id'); and it return to null.

Comment: If that function returns NULL, no sequence has a dependency on the table column. In that case, you will have to look at the default clause of the column definition to figure out which sequence to modify.

Comment: Ok understood. Means that I just need to query SELECT nextval('epil_files_seq_id'); to obtain the next sequence value and boom! got the result. Thanks for the help mate!